# KeyError in freeze model

Tags: python, tensorflow

I've used the TensorFlow's `graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants` function to freeze a `ckpt` model. I have added all nodes in the `ckpt` model to the whitelist of the `convert_variables_to_constants`.

However, when I want to load the freezed model and use it, apparently a few nodes have not been added. I mean in the bellow line:

`logits = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("Logits/BiasAdd:0")`

it gives me the following error:

```
KeyError: "The name 'Logits/BiasAdd:0' refers to a Tensor which does not exist. The operation, 'Logits/BiasAdd', does not exist in the graph."
```

Any ideas how can I add this node to the freezed model?

Comment: [`convert_variables_to_constants`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v1.12.0/tensorflow/python/framework/graph_util_impl.py#L205-L289) prunes the graph and removes everything not needed to compute the given outputs (using `extract_sub_graph`). Make sure that all the nodes you want are necessary for the given outputs, or otherwise you can directly add more nodes as outputs to make sure they get included.

Comment: @jdehesa thanks. How can I include a necessary node to the output graph?

Comment: When you call [`convert_variables_to_constants`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/graph_util/convert_variables_to_constants), add the nodes you want to include to `output_node_names`.